# scrapy error processing url

Tags: python, scrapy

Hi I'm new with python and scrapy, I'm trying to code a spider but I can't find where is the error or a solution for an error while processing the starting url, don't know if it's a problem with xpath or other thing, most of the threads that I found about talks about wrong indentation, but this is not my case.
Code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider

from scrapy_crawls.items import Vino


class BodebocaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Bodeboca"
    allowed_domains = ["bodeboca.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.bodeboca.com/vino/espana',
    )
    counter = 1
    next_url = ""

    vino = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.next_url = self.start_urls[0]


    def parse(self, response):

        for sel in response.xpath(
                '//div[@id="venta-main-wrapper"]/div[@id="venta-main"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/span'):

            #print sel
            # HREF
            a_href = sel.xpath('.//a/@href').extract()
            the_href = a_href[0]
            print the_href
            yield scrapy.Request(the_href, callback=self.parse_item, headers={'Referer': response.url.encode('utf-8'),
                                                                              'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3'})

        # SIGUIENTE URL
        results = response.xpath(
            '//div[@id="wrapper"]/article/div[@id="article-inner"]/div[@id="default-filter-form-wrapper"]/div[@id="venta-main-wrapper"]/div[@class="bb-product-info-sort bb-sort-behavior-attached"]/div[@clsas="bb-product-info"]/span[@class="bb-product-info-count"]').extract()


        if not results:
            raise CloseSpider
        else:
            #self.next_url = self.next_url.replace(str(self.counter), str(self.counter + 1))
            #self.counter += 1
            self.next_url = response.xpath('//div[@id="venta-main-wrapper"]/div[@class="item-list"]/ul[@class="pager"]/li[@class="pager-next"]/a/@href').extract()[0]
            yield scrapy.Request(self.next_url, callback=self.parse, headers={'Referer': self.allowed_domains[0],
                                                                              'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3'})
```

Error:

```
2017-03-28 12:29:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-03-28 12:29:08 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-03-28 12:29:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.bodeboca.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-03-28 12:29:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.bodeboca.com/vino/espana> (referer: None)
/vino/terra-cuques-2014
2017-03-28 12:29:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.bodeboca.com/vino/espana> (referer: None)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
yield next(it)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
for x in result:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/gerardo/proyectos/vinos-diferentes-crawl/scrapy_crawls/spiders/Bodeboca.py", line 36, in parse
'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3'})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
self._set_url(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 57, in _set_url
raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: /vino/terra-cuques-2014
2017-03-28 12:29:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-03-28 12:29:08 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 449,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 38558,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 28, 10, 29, 8, 951654),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/ValueError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 28, 10, 29, 8, 690948)}
2017-03-28 12:29:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: You are passing `the_href` to scrapy and it is just the path part of the url, not a full url.

Comment: Also here `start_urls = (
        'http://www.bodeboca.com/vino/espana',
    )` i think you have a comma to get rid of

Comment: Yeah that comma was the problem, now i'm having other problems, but I'm goig to try to solve it but my self, if I have any other question i will back. Also a ton of thanks for your help

Comment: @desconectad0 you mentionned being new to scrapy. I highly suggest that you take a look at the [CrawlSpider](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider). It will make your life easier.

Comment: Also, if one of you could post a response, so the question can be marked as answered, that would be extra nice :)

Comment: @Mayeul sgc hi, I'm here again searching for a solution for my problems i found that this comma must be there for one single string tuple, so my problem return to be the same what Étieenne said seems to be correct, the case is when I delete the comma the program doesn't enter in parse method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply answer: you extract from page relative url e.g.
    `/vino/terra-cuques-2014`

In order to make a scrapy request url need to be full:
    `http://www.bodeboca.com/vino/terra-cuques-2014`.
You can make full url using Scrapy [response.urljoin()](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#following-links)
method e.g.:
`full_url = response.urljoin(url)`.

Try not to use xpath expression like: `/div[@id="venta-main"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/span` -  it's hard to read and very easy can be broken from slightest change in the page. Instead, you can simply use xpath based on a class: `//a[@class="verficha"]`.

You can rewrite part of your spider like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    links = response.xpath('//a[@class="verficha"]')
    for link in links:
        url = link.xpath('@href').extract_first()
        full_url = response.urljoin(url)
        yield scrapy.Request(full_url , callback= your callback)
```

If you want to extract url to next page you can use xpath `next_page = response.xpath('//li[@class="pager-next"]/a/@href').extract_first()`, again call `response.urljoin(next_page)` etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right in all what you say, also i need to say that i was doing wrong the xpath, I did that div/div/div... just like a test

Comment: @desconectad0 No problem. I'm glad I could help you.